# Python how to add a column to a text file

Tags: python

I'm new to Python and I have a challenge. I need to add a column in a text file delimited by ";". So far so good ... except that the value of this column depends on the value of another column. I will leave an example in case I was not clear

My file looks like this:

```
Account;points
1;500
2;600
3;1500
```

If the value of the points column is greater than 1000, enter 2, if less, enter 1.

In this case the file would look like this:

```
Account;points;column_created
1;500;1
2;600;1
3;1500;2
```

Comment: Show what you tried as properly formatted code in the question.

Comment: To working with `.txt` file If you want to add something to it, first you should read it completely and add your data, after that write it. Its not possible to write without read.

Comment: do you mean 'greater than 100' or 'greater than 1000'?

Comment: if file you can't place new item between other items. You have to read all data to memory, add items in memory, and write all data back to file. Use `pandas` to do this and it will be easy to add new value based on other column.

Comment: ops in the case would be greater than 1000. I will take a look at how Pandas works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an approach without using pandas. This code assumes your points column will always be at the second position.

```
with open('stats.txt', 'r+') as file:
lines = file.readlines()
    file.seek(0,0)
    for line in lines:
        columns = line.strip().split(";")
        if int(columns[1])>1000:
           file.write(";".join(columns)+";2\n")
        else:
            file.write(";".join(columns) + ";1\n")
```

Comment: Thank you, this process worked as I expected. Yes the second column will always be that of points. However, I have not yet calculated its execution time.

Comment: Ah! I forgot to mention, the treatment base has more than 100 million lines, today the process is done in SQL SERVER which is my specialty, however the process takes 60 minutes in total, I am looking for Python for always telling me that for this type task it is the best tool

Comment: I believe this code will handle a big files. On average 1 million lines, makes size between (50-70 mb).  I am assuming if you dealing with that big file then your system already has enough capacity.

Answer (score 2):

A file (hard drive) can't add a new item between new elements. You have to read all the data to memory, add a new column, and write all back to the file.

You could use [Pandas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pandas_%28software%29) to easily add a new column, based on the value from the other column.

In the example I use `io.StringIO()` only to create minimal working code, so everyone can copy it and the text. Use `read_csv('input.csv', sep=';')` with your file:

```
import pandas as pd
import io

text = '''Account;points
1;500
2;600
3;1500'''

#df = pd.read_csv('input.csv', sep=';')
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(text), sep=';')

print('--- Before ---')
print(df)

df['column_created'] = df['points'].apply(lambda x: 2 if x > 1000 else 1)

print('--- After ---')
print(df) #

df.to_csv('output.csv', sep=';', index=False)
```

#### Result

```
--- Before ---
   Account  points
0        1     500
1        2     600
2        3    1500
--- After ---
   Account  points  column_created
0        1     500               1
1        2     600               1
2        3    1500               2
```

Comment: Thanks, the process worked as I expected, but the treatment base has more than 100 million lines, this made the process take a long time =/

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Python '[csv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html)' library to create CSV files. Here is the link to the documentation.